# Checking if a query returns any information

Tags: php, sql

I've been working on this for hours, can't seem to figure out why its not working.

All of the tutorials I've looked at showed that this worked fine. The output of `num_rows` is greater than `1` and yet it still goes inside the `if` statement.

Also it returns `1` even when it should be `0`. Maybe it's a `BOOL`?

```
if($test = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "Username and Email are Available test= $test";
} else {
    echo "Username and Email are TAKEN";
}
```

Comment: if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement only evaluates to `true` if `num_rows` is equal to one:

```
if($test = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
```

You need to change it to more than equals to 1 or more than 0:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){
    echo "Username and Email are Available test= $test";
} else {
    echo "Username and Email are TAKEN";
}
```

---

Usage of [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

> Returns the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: $result = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$query));
combined the two statements and it fixed the problem. idk whay it wasnt working separated.

Comment: @user2376313 I've updated my answer, it would also work if they are separate statements